# ESP32: Is it possible to make a bridge ETH-WIFI

Tags: wifi, ethernet, esp32, bridge, esp-idf

i m using olimex esp32-poe-iso and i m trying to achieve the following:

HOME ROUTER ====== (WIFI) ====== (STA):esp32-poe-iso:(ETH) ====== (ETH cable)===== Jetson Nano

im not trying to find a piece of code here. I m just trying to be sure that it's doable.
i have been trying for days now with no luck.
All the docs and examples out there explain the opposite way around. which worked fine for me.

HOME ROUTER ====== (ETH) ====== (ETH):esp32-poe-iso:(WIFI-AP) ====== (WIFI)===== Jetson Nano
Any clue is really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You want to build a WiFi bridge which allows your wired Jetson Nano board to connect to your WiFi network? Sure, it's possible. Not simple, but definitely doable (assuming you know your networking). At least one person has source code, but googling for "esp32 wifi bridge" brings up quite a few resources.

I'm not sure that the Espressif WiFi library gives you enough control to do it transparently. So we're probably talking about building a NAT box, which requires translating the addresses for your wired client and forwarding the packets. Maybe also a DHCP server, if you don't like to assign IP-s manually. There's a sample NAT implementation here: https://github.com/martin-ger/esp32_nat_router

A more practical solution would be buying a WiFi router which can work as a bridge for Ethernet devices. Some very cheap WiFi routers have this functionality these days (I vaguely recall a TP-LINK device which cost around 20€).